# Hide tag cloud in rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

currently, I am using the gem 'acts-as-taggable-on' in my application. Now I have a tag cloud like this:

```
  <div class="tag_cloud_show pull-sm-right col-sm-2">
    <% tag_cloud Article.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
      <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Now, I want to hide the tag cloud if the window browser width reaches a specific value(I test it by myself, and I don't know whether this is the best way to do it or not). So, I write some jQuery code in my application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   function hideTagCloud () {
      if ($(window).width() < 760)  {
        $(".tag_cloud").hide();
      }
   };

   function showTagCloud () {
      if ($(window).width() >= 760)  {
        $(".tag_cloud").show();
      }
   };
   hideTagCloud();
   showTagCloud();
});
```

The problem I have now is if I call the function showTagCloud(), it won't hide the tag cloud anymore. But if I don't call it, the tag cloud will be hidden not matter size of the browser is. In general, I just want to hide the tag cloud if the user is using a small smartphone, if I don't hide it, it will break the structure of my index and show page. So, could you please take a look at my code, any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

**custom.css.scss**:

```
.tag_cloud {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  .s { font-size: 0.8em; }
  .m { font-size: 1.2em; }
  .l { font-size: 1.8em; }
}

.tag_cloud_show {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  .s { font-size: 0.8em; }
  .m { font-size: 1.2em; }
  .l { font-size: 1.8em; }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought but, since you are using bootstrap (based on the `col-sm-2` class in your div), you can just use their responsive helper classes for that div. Specifically, there are classes to hide a div (element) based on the size of the screen (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). That is, `.hidden-xs` should do the trick on that div

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. But, could you be more specific? You meant I can use bootstrap to hide the tag cloud for small screen sizes?

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I didnt know I could accomplish it with Bootstrap. Currently, I am using bootstrap 4. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Good deal! I think, in your use-case, just using their (Bootstrap) responsive classes will be far more consistent and simpler versus a JS-based solution. Hope it works out!

Comment: @craig.kaminsky, yeah, it works. How can I mark your answer as a solution? Thank you very much. And by the way, your profile is interesting. An officer, a coach, and a web developer huh! ^-^

Comment: Thank you! I live in a VERY small town in the Rocky Mountains so we all do a little bit of everything to get by :). I'll paste my comment into an answer and you can, if you wish, mark that as "correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap - based on the `col-sm-2` class in your div - you can just use Bootstrap's responsive helper classes to show/hide that div/element based on the screen resolution/browser window.

Specifically, the class to hide a div/element based on the size you wish to focus on (< 768) is, `.hidden-xs` and should do the trick for you.

```
<div class="tag_cloud_show pull-sm-right col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
  <% tag_cloud Article.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks again. You made my day sir. Keep doing the good work like this. ^^

Comment: It's my pleasure! Very glad to be able to help out and you have a great rest of your day!